# How does Hibernate Search flatten entites for Lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene, hibernate-search

I want to put millions of entities into Solr for querying by their fields (like range-searches, sorting, grouping etc).

However, the entities I have are not flat. They have relationships like Employee has Company, Person has Address, Cart has List etc. (Note all these are entities or Data-Objects and cannot be put into Solr directly).

I came across Hibernate Search which builds a Lucene index from non-flat entities.
If someone can point me to the code where it does that, it would be great.

I know this is doable since Elasticsearch is also doing this.
But since moving away from Solr might be expensive bet for me, I want to try flattening the entities, either by myself or using HibernateSearch APIs

Comment: Does relationship is many to many? or one to many?

Comment: We have atleast the One-To-One and One-To-Many relationships among the entities. Many-to-many is not yet priortized for the near future.

Comment: so, you could use BlockJoinQuery. Take a look here - http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html it exactly doing what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate Search adds the entity associations as part of the root entity. Say there is a *Person* with an association to *Address* via an *address* property. *Address* has a *street* and *city* property. The Lucene Document for a *Person* instance will then also contain a field *address.street* and *address.city*. To enable this embedded indexing you will need to annotate the *address* property with *@IndexedEmbedded*. See also the online docs of Search - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-associated

Technically Hibernate Search keeps the required meta information of the indexed properties (including the associations) for an entity and on an entity change event (or a change of the association) rebuilds the document/index.

Is this what you were after?

Comment: Hardy, yes this is coming very close to it.

However, I am using Solr actually to index my data. So I need to flatten these entities manually. Do you know of some API in Hibernate Search which can help me do this?

Comment: no, there is no exposed API to do just that. The flattening is part of the core Search engine